# Jssor Slider labels in bullet navigator

Tags: jquery, grid, slider, jssor

with vertical bullet navigator of [Grid Slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/grid-slider.html) I don't want to display numbers for horizontal images (1-4), but user defined text (labels) for every horizontal "album" (e.g. Athens, Beijing, Canada, etc...").

Any idea how to achieve it?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please use thumbnail navigator instead of bullet navigator.

Note that apart from image thumbnail, text thumbnail is also legal.

e.g.

```
<div u="thumb">Athens</div>
```

Please let know if there is any problem.

Comment: Great, it solves the problem! :-) Thank you for answer, and for jssor sliders, too!